# Dropdown CSS - List doesnt select correct

Tags: css

my site: http://matthew.sobeit.co.za/shop

Now hover over "products" then hover "orthodontic material" and submenu will come up, might be fine the first time, but try it again, it almost impossible to select any item in this submenu.

What am i doing wrong, I have looked at the CSS, tried changed the "left: 190px" but it seems to reset itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion: read the FAQ before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something is different on your interior pages than your homepage. I didn't get a chance to figure out exactly what, but the solution is to move the sub-menu to the left a little bit more.

```
#main-nav ul ul {
   left: 185px;
   top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to do this but it keeps changing itself back to 190px

Comment: Nevermind, I had to change it in the theme "custom css" menu as opposed to style.css